# Install Lubuntu w/o Disc or Flash Drive?

Tags: lubuntu, system-installation, flash, windows-xp, cd

My WinXP desktop was recently blasted with a few bits of malware. I removed the malware but the damage is done, and my OS is finally at its end; it's barely chugging along as it is. So, I'm figuring what I'd like to do is replace the OS with Lubuntu, which I know is a lightweight, heavily WinXP-esque distro of Linux.

However, every article, every explanation, I've read online has stated I need either a 4+ GiB flash drive or a burnable CD. Well, I have a flash drive, but it's only 1 GiB; and I have a disc burner, but no disc. So, frankly, I doubt I'll be able to do it. But hey, I figured I might as well ask away here on AU; what have I got to lose?

So my question is this: would it be possible to replace my WinXP OS w/ Lubuntu without using either a 4+ GiB flash drive or a burnable CD?

Thanks very much. I appreciate any help you could give.

Answer (score 2):

I have an Ubuntu 14 x86 USB image on an 8GB pendrive, it only takes up 987.1MB.
So I would be seriously surprised if a Lubuntu image wouldn't fit on your 1GB pendrive... the Lubuntu iso (12.04) is only 721MB in size.

I do have to say I've created it with pendrive linux (on windows), not unetbootin.

Answer (score 1):

I Used 16GB Memory Card to Install Ubuntu, and it Uses around 1GB, so i think Lubuntu is more LightWight, You Can use an SDcard from your Smartphone but Becarful everything will be Wiped, it's not a good idea i dont recommend it at all,

Besides that, i dont know Your PC Specs But Lubuntu Sucks a bit, you feel like you are back to 80's, if you dont care for Style and being Modern, than Never mind

Ubuntu is LightWight as Well, in the Past i Had Ubuntu 13.04 Installed on a Pentium 4 PC with 1GB of RAM and a Horrible 80GB IDE HDD and Ubuntu Performed Very Well, But not Fast, Searching was the slowest thing cause of RAM, when i upgraded it's RAM it worked flawlessly for Browsing Internet and Doing Simple things, but When it Comes to Working Proffesional, it's not Good, so Think Twice.

I Just Remembered that i had similar Situation While Installing Windows 8,i Installed using Partition with Couple of gigs, You Can Repartition you HDD but this will wipe everything, or you could Try Using some bootable utilities to Shrink a Piece of your C: Partition

Comment: I read this too late.  It wiped out my 2TB hard drive of all my personal memories since year 2000.  I wonder if the data can be recovered?  Does it re-format the partitions? 
 * sob *

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly partition your hard drive (just 4-8GB), use unetbootin to write the iso to there, and then boot from the partition. Then install it over the bigger one.

Comment: It works, but it seems to wipe out all other partitions in the physical drive...

Answer (score 0):

LUbuntu iso file is just 650MB

check this link

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu#Downloading_Lubuntu_14.04

download that iso and burn it to your USB flash drive and install it.

after that you can install ubuntu dekstop with this command

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

if burn process failed due to insufficient disk space, you can try

http://www.slax.org/

or

http://puppylinux.org/

download that iso and burn it to your USB flash drive.

u still can install ubuntu on linux but you must do it with yourself

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  I have installed Lubuntu 14.04 from a 1 GB flash drive.  It is not difficult and the 1GB is more than enough for Lubuntu.

1. If you have not already downloaded the ISO download it from
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu
2. Check the MD5Sum
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
3. Burn the ISO to the flash drive.  You can use your Windows XP to create the bootable flash drive using UNetbootin or Live USB Creator.
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Creating_a_bootable_Ubuntu_USB_flash_drive_from_Windows

Comment: The question is about not using a flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

I have an old Windows XP computer just like you (a Dell Dimension 3000) that was built in 2004 and it can boot from USB. Look around in your BIOS' settings and see if you can change the disk order (which your BIOS very likely uses) AND your boot order. They are both two different kinds of order. Also, try updating your BIOS if you can flash it. I bet your computer can. Just look at ALL of the settings in your BIOS (even ones not related to boot) and see if you can figure it out, as disk order is often called something different in different BIOSes. An alternative is to use the alternate installer from a floppy disk.